# Finding a group of subsets that does not overlap

Tags: algorithm, optimization, subset

I am reviewing for an upcoming programming contest and was working on the following problem:

Given a list of integers, an integer t, an integer r, and an integer p, determine if the list contains t sets of 3, r runs of 3, and p pairs of numbers. For each of these subsets, the numbers must be adjacent and any given number can only exist in one subset, if any at all.

Currently, I am solving the problem by simply finding all sets of 3, runs of 3, and pairs and then checking all permutations until finding one which has no overlapping subsets. This seems inefficient, however, and I was wondering if there was a better solution to the problem.

Here are two examples of the problem:

{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 0}, t = 1, r = 1, p = 2.
This works because we have the triple {4 4 4}, the run {1 2 3}, and the pairs {1 1} and {5 5}

{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}, t = 1, r = 1, p = 1
This does not work because the only triple is {1 1 1} and the only run is {1 2 3} and the two overlap (They share a 1).

I am looking for a more efficient approach to this problem.

Comment: Must set of 3 or pair contain consecutive elements?

Comment: Yes, they must be consecutive elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a faster way, but you can solve this with dynamic programming. Compute a recursive function F(t,r,p,n) which decides whether it is possible to have t triples, r runs, and p pairs in the sequence starting at position 1 and ending at n, and storing the last subset of the solution ending at position n if it is possible. If you can have a triple, run, or pair ending at position n then you have a recursive case, either. F(t-1,r,p,n-3) or F(t,r-1,p,n-3) or F(t,r,p-1,n-2), and you have the last subset stored, or otherwise you have a recursive case F(t,r,p,n-1). This looks like fourth power complexity but it really isn't, because the value of n is always decreasing so the complexity is actually O(n + TRP), where T is the total desired number of triples, R is the total desired number of runs, and P is the total desired number of pairs. So O(n^3) in the worst case.